# RPGLE CRTPGM "Definition not found for symbol 'OPENMSGQ'" issue for Websphere MQ OpenMsgQ command

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Which module needs to be included on the CRTPGM command to enable compilation to be successful, when creating a RPGLE program which has "callp(e) OpenMsgQ" - the MQ Series open message queue command in it. Have tried MODULE(OPENMSGQ) without success. Have tried running an existing program in debug and viewing modules but no mq modules were present. Any ideas or approaches to diagnose further will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding BNDSRVPGM((MQADAPT)) to the CRTPGM command solved the issue.